# How i fix the 'Class not registered' error

Tags: c++, winapi

i have a C++ Win32 application.

I want add a button but when i start my application, i get a 'Class not registered' error.

Im using Windows 11 build 22000.613 on x64 machine

I have tried both x64 and x86 version of the program

Please help me!

C++ code :

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{

    // Register the window class.
    const wchar_t CLASS_NAME[] = L"Sample Window Class";

    WNDCLASS wc = { };

    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpszClassName = CLASS_NAME;

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    // Create the window.

    HWND hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        0,                              // Optional window styles.
        CLASS_NAME,                     // Window class
        L"Learn to Program Windows",    // Window text
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,            // Window style

        // Size and position
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,

        NULL,       // Parent window    
        NULL,       // Menu
        hInstance,  // Instance handle
        NULL        // Additional application data
    );

    if (hwnd == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    ShowWindow(hwnd, nCmdShow);

    // Run the message loop.
    MSG msg = { };
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            L"Button",
            L"Giai PTB2",
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |
            WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            100,
            100,
            100,
            24,
            hwnd,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        // All painting occurs here, between BeginPaint and EndPaint.
        FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1));
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    }
    return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Program log :

```
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Users\pc2\Document\VS2022\Projects\WindowsProject1\Debug\WindowsProject1.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\win32u.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32full.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp_win.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbase.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\vcruntime140d.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ucrtbased.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\combase.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel.appcore.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\TextInputFramework.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreMessaging.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\CoreUIComponents.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WinTypes.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll'. 
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\clbcatq.dll'. 
onecore\com\combase\objact\objact.cxx(4080)\combase.dll!769F9977: (caller: 769E5CE6) ReturnHr(1) tid(4938) 80040154 Class not registered
'WindowsProject1.exe' (Win32) : Chargé 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleacc.dll'. 
The thread 0x2f24 stopped with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1a8c stopped with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2960 stopped with 0 (0x0).
The program '[6768] WindowsProject1.exe' stopped with code 0 (0x0).
```

(I have translated the log in english because the log is french)

Here is the original :
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIozy.png)

Comment: error in your code ? are `CreateWindowEx` fail ?

Comment: No, the error is in the execution of the software, not the build.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think - confusingly - that it's the window class it's complaining about - rather it appears to be a COM class registration that's missing, but since you're not explicitly doing anything COM-related here, I am not sure what the issue is.

Comment: you haven't break at message `WM_CREATE`, so the window continue to `WM_DESTROY` when creating.

Comment: It is not an error, it is debug output.  Enabled by you using a debugger.  combase.dll is very chatty about internal mishaps, important for programmers that write WinRT programs.  They need that kind of help, deeply nested errors inside Microsoft's C++ code can be quite hard to diagnose in that framework.  Since you did not write COM code, the debug output is not relevant to you.  Do fix the bug in the WM_CREATE case statement.

Comment: What i have activated?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, you forgot to `break;`

```
case WM_CREATE:
        CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            L"Button",
            L"Giai PTB2",
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |
            WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
            100,
            100,
            100,
            24,
            hwnd,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            NULL);
        break;
```

Comment: @Raphael If you have got any chance to check my answer?If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.